# Optional ManyToOne produces javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find

Tags: hibernate

Following relates to non-standard table layout, which came into existence as a needed optimization. This question is about how to map this in this schema, not about modifying the schema for better (which might be possible).

Consider table `A`, which has "foreign key" `X` but there is no foreign key constraint on it. Then there are table `B` and `C`, which had PK corresponding to value of `A.X`. Table `A` thus can be in 0,1 or 2 relations, with tables `B`, `C`, both or none.

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @JoinColumn(name = "x", insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private B b;
```

same for C. Now when I try to fetch entiy A, I'm getting `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` when trying to load `b`. Yes, fk `x` is set, `c` exists, `b` does not.

I do not understand, why this is happening especially when I explicitly said, that `@ManyToOne` is optional. It can be solved using `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` but I don't undestand why would I have to use that.

Comment: at database level do you have A.x containing values that do not exist in B.id?

Comment: yes. To rephrase it, `A.x` contain value, which should be "foreign key" to B/C if the record exist there. So say A.x contains UUID, and there is record by that UUID in B table, but there ins't record by that UUID in C table. I undertand that this is not normal decomposition, I'm aware of that, if I'm starting new schema, I wouldn't opt for this, sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@NotFound` annotation of Hibernate to model what should happen in this case. Also see the documentation for more information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-not-found